# Erro Conexão MySql PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, mysqli, phpmyadmin, sql-select

Boa noite pessoal,

estou tentando conectar minha aplicação wordPress com o banco de dados remoto, para poder listar os usuários dentro da aplicação.

Já testei algumas coisas entre algumas pesquisas, mas não consegui resolver o problema ainda.

**Alguém sabe me dizer o que está errado no código?**

**Estou usando o seguinte código:**

```
<?php
define('hostname', 'http://thorpeinnovation.com/painfree/');
define('user', 'admin');
define('password', 'senha');
define('databaseName', 'osmoc913_wp786');
$connect = mysqli_connect(hostname, user, password, databaseName, 80) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

$query = sprintf("SELECT name FROM wp2n_frm_items");

$dados = mysql_query($query, $connect) or die(mysql_error());

$linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados);

$total = mysql_num_rows($dados);
?>

<html>
    <head>
    <title>Exemplo</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

    if($total > 0) {
        do {
?>
            <p><?=$linha['name']?> </p>
<?php
        }while($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados));
    // fim do if 
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($dados);
?>
```

**E está retornando esses erros:**

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host 'https://thorpeinnovation.com/painfree/wp-content/plugins/wp-phpmyadmin-extension/lib/phpMyAdmin_nwuP' (0) in /home/osmoc913/public_html/thorpeinnovation.com/painfree/wp-content/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/shortcode-handler.php(65) : eval()'d code on line 6

Fatal error: in /home/osmoc913/public_html/thorpeinnovation.com/painfree/wp-content/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/shortcode-handler.php(65) : eval()'d code on line 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve informar o endereço do banco de dados (seu `hostname`), que pode sim ser um domínio, mas não deve conter o http ou caminhos.

```
define('hostname', 'thorpeinnovation.com');
```

Caso não funcione tente informar o endereço de IP do servidor.

Outra coisa é a função `mysqli_connect`, que pode receber a porta do banco de dados, porém quase nunca é a porta 80 como informado, tente alterar para porta `3306`

```
$connect = mysqli_connect(hostname, user, password, databaseName, 3306)
```

Também é válido observar que a query SQL não parece puxar os nomes de usuários, a não ser que você utilize uma tabela com padrão de nome diferente.

Por padrão o Wordpress usa a tabela `PREFIX_users`, no seu caso provavelmente `wp2n_users`, com nome da coluna `user_nicename`.

Com base nisso, talvez você tenha que alterar a linha abaixo também.

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT name FROM wp2n_frm_items");
```

Como últimas dicas, você não precisa desse sprintf na linha acima, pode usar somente:

```
$query = "SELECT name FROM wp2n_frm_items";
```

Também observe que você utiliza funções `mysqli` em alguns lugares e em outros funções `mysql`, tente utilizar a variantes do `mysqli` se possível sempre (mysqli_query, mysqli_fetch_assoc, mysqli_num_rows).

Fonte: https://usersinsights.com/wordpress-user-database-tables/

Comment: Agora mudou o erro, diz que o acesso é negado.

**Warning: mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'admin'@'50.116.87.234' (using password: YES) in /home/osmoc913/public_html/thorpeinnovation.com/painfree/wp-content/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/shortcode-handler.php(65) : eval()'d code on line 6**

Comment: Senha incorreta ou usuário sem permissão ao banco dados.

Comment: Procure um arquivo chamado `wp-config.php` na raiz do servidor, ele deve conter os dados do banco de dados do seu wordpress.

Comment: Eu estou usando o Wordpress 5.1.1 na versão web. Sabe me indicar com mais precisão onde esse arquivo se encontra no projeto? Porque outra pessoa comentou sobre ele antes, e ainda não consegui encontrá-lo.

Comment: Na raiz do seu servidor, ao se conectar no servidor por ftp você ou deve ver uma lista de arquivos onde um deles é o `wp-config.php` ou deve ver uma lista com uma pasta chamada `public_html` ou `www`, se ver alguma dessas pastas provavelmente o arquivo está dentro da pasta.